# .NET Session Alternative in Global Scope

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, scope

**Quick question:** Is there a "per-user" data storage object (similar to `Session`) that I can store data in the global scope (similar to `HttpRuntime.Cache`)? Almost as if `Session` and `HttpRuntime.Cache` had a baby.

**Full Background:** I have a ASP.NET website that was originally written for a single thread. Now I changed it so that certain actions will spawn a background thread and the browser polls a service to get status updates.

The problem I am having with this is that certain pieces of data are stored into the HttpContext.Session[] object (membership authentication token, for example). These pieces of data need to be unique to each user and accessible to the background thread. Session is not available to the background thread.

I am aware of `HttpRuntime.Cache` but that would require micromanagement to segment out the users and to expire it at the same time the session is expired. `Session`, on the other hand, automatically expires this things at the right times that I want it too and is already used by things like the `SqlMembershipProvider`.

My question is, is there something that behaves similar to the Session but exists in the global scope?

Comment: @jlafay you actually made me LOL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is anything like you need out of the box.  I would do the following though:

1. User the application cache
2. Make the key the user ID or unique identifier
3. Store a `Dictionary` or some object list in the value for the user.  Use this to store all the data you require.
4. Consider all prepending something on the user ID if you think there could be a conflict with the user unique identifier (eg domain etc)
5. Make sure to set an expiry on the cached data similar to the session (eg sliding)

Comment: There seems like there might be some some dangers

Comment: @Jeff dangers?  Can you elaborate.  If you have access to the `Cache`, this method should do everything you need.  It's just a hybrid.  I wouldn't recommend doing the session copying approach that Alexei mentioned in a comment.

Comment: Ooops. I started writing this comment but never meant to send it. I didnt even realize it was posted until I got this response. Thats why it didnt make any sense. Originally, I was concerned about scope, but I worked things out on my own. Sorry!

Comment: Im going the Dictionary way. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try passing the `HttpContext.Current` object to the method on your background thread. You should be able to access the session from the background thread through `currentContext.Session` assuming `currentContext` is the `HttpContext`  parameter that was passed in.

See this [blog post](http://odetocode.com/articles/112.aspx) on how to safely access the HttpContext object from multiple threads.

Comment: Context is not available after request ends (like in OP case).

Comment: Nice blog post! I was excited about passing context when I first read your response, but now after the blog post, I'll have to spend a little extra time thinking if its really safe and what I need.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Since when application pool restarts all backgound activity die I suggest to think about moving user's state to your own database or external storage. Unfortunately you'll lose automatic session management benifits (sliding expiration), but if you need backgound activity it will work better - i.e. you'll be able to move your activity out of IIS process to separate process/machine if needed later.

Comment: I'm not worried about losing data on application restarts. External storage would give me another way to access the session data outside of the httpcontext though.

Comment: In this case I'd simply clone content of Session (as it is string to object dictionary) and pass it to worker thread(s). Note that in case of in-memory state objects in session state are not copies of data in session state (unlike in SQL/session service state), so be carefull not to change that data in your worker threads.